# how to (correctly) use an enumerated type with livebindings (TObjectBindSourceAdapter)

Tags: delphi, enums, livebindings

I'm using `TObjectBindSourceAdapter` to use livebindings with an object. 
One of the properties of the object i'm using with `TObjectBindSourceAdapter` has an enumerated type, but the field in the adapter is never generated when i use an enumerated type in my object

The Only solution i have found for now is to define the enumerated type as an integer in my object and typecast it. This seems to work fine but you have to keep type casting from and back the enumerated type and integers.

Here is some example code to explain what i mean.

First example which uses the enumerated type that i tried initially and does not seem to work:

```
 uses Data.Bind.ObjectScope;

 Type
   TMyEnumtype = (meOne, meTwo, meThree);

   TMyObject = class
     public
       MyEnumType: TMyEnumtype;
  end;

procedure TForm9.But1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyObject: TMyObject;
  aBindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter;
begin
  MyObject := TMyObject.Create;
  MyObject.MyEnumType := meTwo;
  aBindSourceAdapter := TObjectBindSourceAdapter<TMyObject>.Create(nil, MyObject, False);
  if aBindSourceAdapter.FindField('MyEnumType') <> nil then
    ShowMessage('MyEnumType found')
  else
    showmessage('MyEnumType not found');
  FreeAndNil(MyObject);
  FreeAndNil(aBindSourceAdapter);
end;
```

Second example that seems to work by typecasting to integers

```
uses Data.Bind.ObjectScope;

Type
  TMyEnumtype = (meOne, meTwo, meThree);

  TMyObject = class
    public
      MyEnumType: integer;
  end;

procedure TForm9.But1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyObject: TMyObject;
  aBindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter;
  aEnumType : TMyEnumtype;
begin
  MyObject := TMyObject.Create;
  MyObject.MyEnumType := Integer(meTwo);
  aBindSourceAdapter := TObjectBindSourceAdapter<TMyObject>.Create(nil, MyObject, False);
  if aBindSourceAdapter.FindField('MyEnumType') <> nil then
    ShowMessage('MyEnumType found')
  else
    showmessage('MyEnumType not found');

  aEnumType := TMyEnumtype(aBindSourceAdapter.FindField('MyEnumType').GetTValue.AsInteger);

  if aEnumType =  meTwo then
    showmessage('meTwo');

  FreeAndNil(MyObject);
  FreeAndNil(aBindSourceAdapter);
end;
```

I was wondering if someone else had come across this problem and if there is perhaps some other solution to solve this without reverting to integers and keep using the enumerated types. I'm also not sure if my workaround is the common way to do this or not.

Comment: I think you have no choice - I've come to the conclusion long ago that casting as integers is the best solution for this.

Comment: Reported as a bug in RAD Studio Quality here -> quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-34259. I recognize it could have been flagged as an Improvement though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best way is to register a converter.  It turns out to be very easy, but only after digging through the VCL source code.  I didn't find any useful documentation.  But here it is.

```
unit MyConverters;

interface

uses System.Rtti, System.Bindings.Outputs;

type
  TMyEnum = (Value1, Value2, Value3);

implementation

procedure RegisterConverters;
begin
  TValueRefConverterFactory.RegisterConversion(TypeInfo(TMyEnum), TypeInfo(string),
    TConverterDescription.Create(
      procedure(const InValue: TValue; var OutValue: TValue)
      var
        MyEnum: TMyEnum;
        S: string;
      begin
        MyEnum := InValue.AsType<TMyEnum>;
        case MyEnum of
          Value1:  S := 'First Value';
          Value2:  S := 'Second Value';
          Value3:  S := 'Third Value';
          else     S := 'Other';
        end;
        OutValue := TValue.From<string>(S);
      end,
      'TMyEnumToString',
      'TMyEnumToString',
      '', // TODO what is the AUnitName param used for?
      True, // TODO what is ADefaultEnabled used for?  What does it mean?
      'Converts a TMyEnum value to a string',
      nil)
  );
end;

initialization
  RegisterConverters;
end.
```

In a nutshell, you call `TValueRefConverterFactor.RegisterConversion()` and pass in:

- The type that this converter converts **FROM**
- The type that this converter converts **TO**
- A TConverterDescription that contains an anonymous procedure to actually perform the conversion along with some other metadata.

In the above code, the `initialization` section calls `RegisterConverters`, so all that is necessary is to include the unit in your project and the live bindings framework will use the converter whenever it needs to convert a `TMyEnum` value to a `string`.

Comment: I'm afraid this solution cannot work, at least with current Delphi - Sydney 10.4:
A quick look at Data.Bind.ObjectScope.pas, class procedure TBindSourceAdapter.AddPropertiesToList(...) says:
        case LProperty.PropertyType.TypeKind of
          tkEnumeration:
            if SameText(LTypeName, 'boolean') or SameText(LTypeName, 'bool') then // 'bool' for C++
              LCollectionEditorField := CreateRttiPropertyField<Boolean>(LProperty,
                ABindSourceAdapter, AGetMemberObject, mtBoolean);
The above has little chance to add a enumerated field to the TBindSourceAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Casting enums as integers and back is really the appropriate way to accommodate for this. Let's say for example...

```
type
  TMyEnum = (meOne, meTwo, meThree);
```

As you already demonstrate, these can be casted as integers. When casting as an integer, it uses the index in which each one is listed in the definition. So...

```
0 = meOne
1 = meTwo
2 = meThree
```

You would cast `TMyEnum` as `Integer` like...

```
Something := Integer(MyEnumValue);
```

and then cast it back like...

```
Something := TMyEnum(MyIntegerValue);
```

This is widely used to solve your exact issue, and I use it all the time myself. I investigated the same scenario long ago and came to the conclusion that it's really the only way to do this - unless you want to do some more sophisticated conversion such as using strings...

```
function MyEnumToStr(const MyEnum: TMyEnum): String;
begin
  case MyEnum of
    meOne: Result:= 'meOne';
    meTwo: Result:= 'meTwo';
    meThree: Result:= 'meThree';
  end;
end;

function StrToMyEnum(const Str: String): TMyEnum;
var
  S: String;
begin
  S:= UpperCase(Str);
  if S = 'MEONE' then Result:= meOne
  else if S = 'METWO' then Result:= meTwo
  else if S = 'METHREE' then Result:= meThree;
end;
```

(I'm sure there are other ways of using `if` statements for `StrToMyEnum`)

Using strings in this manner can make things more readable. A more real-world example...

```
type
  TCustomerType = (cmRetail, cmWholesale, cmDesigner);
```

where...

```
cmRetail = 'Retail Customer'
cmWholesale = 'Wholesale Customer'
cmDesigner = 'Designer Customer'
```